# Using mercurial, I added a new file and wrote code in it, then deleted that file. Can I retrieve it?

Tags: mercurial

Pretty much the title. I've looked at a lot of similar questions asked here, and I can't seem to find something that applies.

Started by syncing with HEAD. Created a few new files. Filled in those files, they were being tracked at this point. I then not only deleted the files, but also removed them from being tracked (because of stupid UI). According to my understanding, those files are gone for good, but I thought I'd check with people who are smarter than me: Is it possible to retrieve them?

Comment: Did you commit the files after filing them in but before deleting them?

Comment: Assuming you committed your changes to those files, you can absolutely recover them. If you did not commit them, then no you cannot recover them using Mercurial.

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial does not store uncommitted changes, so if you did not commit the files then they are lost.

If you did commit them, then `hg update -C` will restore them (and all other files --- make sure there are no other changes you haven't committed and want to keep) to the latest commit for your working dir.